# Create new mongoDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I installed MongoDB 4.0 in local host. There are 3 default database as below

```
> show dbs
admin   0.078GB
config  0.078GB
local   0.078GB
```

Then I tried to create a new db using nodejs

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://local:27017/mydatabase"; // mydatabase is the name of db 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created!");
    db.close();
});
```

Above code work fine. I can see message "Database created!".

However , when I show dbs again , newly created **mydatabase** does not show up. There are still 3 databases .

```
> show dbs
admin   0.078GB
config  0.078GB
local   0.078GB
```

May I know what I did wrong ?

Thanks
ALex

Comment: `MongoDB waits until you have created a collection (table), with at least one document (record) before it actually creates the database (and collection).`

Answer (score 3):

Important thing to know while creating MongoDB database is that **A database is not created until it gets content!** . You need to create at least one collection.

Hopes this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

**Your MongoDb database will not be created until you create at least one collection with at least one record**, so create a collection and add at least one record in it to see the database using 'show dbs'.